# Getting the OS theme color values in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, background-color

I just want to get the background color values of any widget (button, list item, textbox) when it's hovered and it's selected, which i'm looking to use in my custom stylesheet.

For better understanding I'm attaching the following screen shots taken in Ubuntu. The same is applicable for Windows also.

With hover effect : 
[image: withhovereffect]

With selected effect :
 [image: withselectedeffect]

Answer (score 1):

The selected color is returned by `QPalette.color()` for the key `QPalette.Highlight`.
And in a stylesheet, you can use `{ background-color: palette(highlight) }`.

The hover background color doesn't seem to be part of the `QPalette` colors, but is apparently either painted as part of the native widgets API (gtk), or hardcoded into the `QStyle` classes.

Comment: Thanks alexisdm. Part of my problem is solved. The class description explains everything clearly. http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpalette.html. Sorry i can't understand your second point. Are you saying that there is no way to get hover background color values or can we get default values?.

Comment: There is no way to get the hover colors with Qt. They are used internally, but are not exposed to the API.